# Execute XPages SSJS code if complete refresh, not partial refresh?

Tags: xpages

I have an XPage with some SSJS code that I'd like to execute in the case of a complete refresh.  (It's also okay if it executes on initial page load, I guess.)  If a partial refresh of a component on the page has occurred on the page, then I don't want the code to execute.  Is it possible to distinguish these cases?  It feels like I need to set a state variable in viewScope to be able to do this.

For context, the partial refresh is a user clicking on the links of a pager to move through chunks of view elements.  The intitial/complete refresh case is performing a FTSearch on the view.  That should only be done when the user clicks on other links on the page that are used to filter the view.

The XPages lifecycle and event handlers are still a mystery in some ways....  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your SSJS to the `beforePageLoad` or `afterPageLoad`, depending on what's available). Those events are only triggered during the initial page load, which you can see by adding `print("Running beforeRenderResponse");` to the event and looking at the server console.

In events where you want to run the code again, use `context.reloadPage();` at the end.

The same XPages lifecycle is processed for `refreshMode="partial"` and `refreshMode="complete"`.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  For a long time, I figured that it wasn't true that partial and complete followed the same lifecycle.  I just assumed for some reason that "complete" was similar to context.reloadPage().  By the way, that brings up another bit of confusion; if I do context.reloadPage(), will I lose the contents of viewScope?

Comment: Correct. It's loading a separate instance of the component tree (the server-side map of the page) rather than picking up a pre-existing one. You could set a sessionScope variable and, in beforePageLoad, then remove it / move it to viewScope.